# when running npm version, use that new version on preversion task

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using `npm version [patch|minor|major]` to manage versions on my module.

But when running the task (`npm version`), I need the new version number to be used on a task (to print that version on the minified file, for example):

```
"preversion": "npm run grunt build --package-version={$something} && foo"
```

Is it possible to get the version number being generated to be used on the `npm preversion` task?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the task on the `version` script on the `package.json` file, so when the task `version` runs, it has the new version number on the `package.json`.